# Media recorder start failed using android things

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-things

Hi i get the following error whenever I try to setup and start a video recording in android.

here is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
    at com.jr.survailancedropboxcam.VideoCameraRecorder.setMediaOutputSurface(VideoCameraRecorder.kt:88)
    at com.jr.survailancedropboxcam.VideoCameraRecorder.access$setMediaOutputSurface(VideoCameraRecorder.kt:26)
    at com.jr.survailancedropboxcam.VideoCameraRecorder$cameraStateCalback$1.onOpened(VideoCameraRecorder.kt:46)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:134)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Here is my code:

```
 mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA)
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT)
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(context.filesDir.absolutePath + "/"+System.currentTimeMillis())
    mediaRecorder.prepare()
    mediaRecorder.start()

    var outputCaptures = ArrayList<Surface>()
    outputCaptures.add(mediaRecorder.surface)

    return outputCaptures
```

crash occurs when i try to call mediaRecorder.start

Comment: and what is your camera hardware setup?

Comment: Raspberry pi 3 with the modular camera connected to it

Comment: try checking for available cameras, and then setting according camera